# Identity Server Refresh Token Resource Owner Password Credential Flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer to control access to an API. I have a separate authentication API which issues the tokens and validates access requests to secure API's.

I give users the ability to generate an access token through a secure web application. I am using the resource owner password credential flow.

Is there a way I can issue a refresh token without the user having to log in and request it? Or is there a way I can set the expiration of the initial access token?

**Code**

This is the code i'm using to generate tokens.

```
DiscoveryResponse disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:27144");
  TokenClient tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "My Client", "MySecret");
  TokenResponse tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("testUser", "testPassword");
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information? If you're setting `AllowOfflineAccess = True` the IdentityServer automatically returns a `refresh_token`. You can also set the `AccessTokenLifetime`...

Comment: @moritzg I set the allowOfflineAccess flag to true and set the absoluteRefreshTokenLifetime to 31540000 which should be a year. However the token response object returns 3600 for the expiresIn property. I can see that a refresh_token is returned also. Do I pass that in the authorization header?

Comment: Which token do you mean by "token response object"?

Comment: @moritzg I've added code to the question. The token response object i'm talking about is the object returned when i call the method RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this can be accomplished with Refresh Tokens.

- Set `AllowOfflineAccess = true` on the client config
- Include `offline_access` in the scope on the initial token request

The token response will now include a RefreshToken in addition to the AccessToken. Return the AccessToken to the client and hold on to the RefreshToken.

When a new AccessToken is needed, request one using the RequestRefreshTokenAsync method on TokenClient. The name is confusing - you are actually requesting a new AccessToken FROM the RefreshToken.

```
TokenResponse refreshTokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync("RefreshTokenGoesHere");
```

There are two ways to manage the RefreshToken expiration. This is controlled by the `RefreshTokenExpiration` property:

- Sliding Expiration
- Absolute Expiration

If sliding expiration is set, the refresh token lifetime will renew after each refresh.

There's also a `RefreshTokenUsage` property, which determines if a token's can be reused or are one-use only. If set to one-use only with sliding expiration, you'll simply get a new RefreshToken to hold on to on each request.

For expiration timing, there's `SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime` and `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime`. Both can be used simulatenousely. For example, if sliding refresh tokens were enabled, the sliding expiration could be 30 days while the absolute expiration could be 1 year. This would allow the user 30 days of inactivity before needing to log in again, but if the user stays active, 1 year of login-free use.

It's important to note in all cases the RefreshToken should never be returned to the user - only the access token should. You'll need some data storage mechanism to hold on to the refresh tokens and their expiration dates.

Comment: #Kevin Gysberg how can we pass offline_access with apiname in scope

Answer (score 4):

I stand by kg743's answer, but for anyone else stuck I believe I can save some trouble:

Include the scope with a *space*, like this:

```
Scopes = "scope1 scope2 offline_access scope3"
```

I kept including it with a comma(,) or semi-colon(;) and it couldn't work for me.